# Free alternative to Videostream

Tags: gratis, video, chromecast

Basically I just need anything to play multiple video files from my Windows desktop to Chromecast.

I can't believe noone has made anything open-source for this yet, considering the only software I can find (Videostream) charges 35$ for basic functionality like a playlist.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. What specific features do you need? What is it you like about Videostream (and want to have), and what are you missing (but need)? Also, you're asking about "free" (tag `gratis`) but talking about "open source". Should it be both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enjoycast](http://enjoycast.tv/) seems like a good alternative. Lets you play local files, Torrent files, videos found on the web, etc.